# How to give user input dynamically in API?

Tags: python, django

I am making an API using Django. Since I am giving static type input and getting output in `json` format. how to give userinput dynamically.

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
from django.views.generic import TemplateView 
from .models import *
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.views.generic.edit import FormView
from .forms import TweetForm
from django.views import View
import json
import pdb
import tweepy
from pprint import pprint
import pickle

consumer_key = 'VR95CmIMrv7q7vfDoPcjC8NZS'
consumer_secret = 'YlWo6BzDnhXozSZnvnN1cIcjvRKrJFJVnYA9vvqMDocOdjyBNu'
access_key = '1006840281361047553-JQPFugH9xVNifKRY1b4BjgpdTLiVND'
access_secret =   '5R3DXQmf6Xf3FwZHZzqSU3P3oYQAReUqwux9ttj5Gj7K5'
def get_tweets(request):
    auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
    auth.set_access_token(access_key, access_secret)
    api = tweepy.API(auth)
    number_of_tweets=10
    tweets = api.user_timeline("realdonaldtrump") 
    tmp= []
    for tweet in tweets:
    tmp.append({"text":tweet.text,"user":tweet.user.name,"retweet_count":tweet.retweet_count,"img":tweet.user.profile_image_url})

    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(tmp))
```

urls.py

```
  from django.conf.urls import url
  from . import views

  urlpatterns = [
url(r'Tweet/$', views.get_tweets, name='Tweet'),

]
```

that output is right but we can see `tweets = api.user_timeline("realdonaldtrump")` line in `views.py` `static` input.how to give it dynamically

Comment: What's wrong with passing it in the request's querystring ?

Comment: You may want to recreate those secrets and try to not to share those in the future. I'm guessing people may guess where those tokens are from by looking at the libraries you use.

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_tweets(request, user):
    ...
    tweets = api.user_timeline(user) 
    ...
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(tmp))
```

With adding user to view function, you need to change the url a bit

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'Tweet/(?P<user>[a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+)/$', views.get_tweets, name='Tweet'),
]
```

Or you can use the get key and values from the link with `request.GET.get('user')` and pass that in without needing to `/Tweet/realdonaldtrump/` but in that case it would be `/Tweet/?user=realdonaldtrump` so it is your choice to choose whichever you want.